# How to avoid animateTransition(transitionContext) protocol method(in navigationController push methods) from removing previous ViewController's view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

i have to push a viewController that has a dimming view with an alpha of 0.5. Because of this, the ViewController's view has to show the previous controller's view behind this dimming background. The problem is that i'm using a navigationController that uses a UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol to customize the animation. By default, after pushing the new viewController onto the stack, the navigationController automatically removes the previous view. So, how to keep the previous view after completing this transition, is this possible?

NOTES: i don't want to just add the controller's view to the navigationController(This gave me strange behaviors in the navigation functionality), and i do really need to push it in this way, so i can continue using the application code pattern.

CODE:

```
func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    if isPresenting {
        let ContainerView = transitionContext.containerView()
        if let PresentedController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey) {
            if let PresentedView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey) {
            PresentedView.alpha         = 0
            PresentedView.frame         = transitionContext.finalFrameForViewController(PresentedController)

            ContainerView.addSubview(PresentedView)
            // i've also tried to add the fromView in the containerView.

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
                PresentedView.alpha     = 1
            }) {
                Completion in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(Completion)
            }
        }
        }
    } else {
        // dismiss code...
    }
}
```

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar situation a few weeks ago. In my case, I was presenting my view controller modally. The way I got around the problem was to take a snapshot of the fromViewController's view and use it as background for toViewController's view.

To capture snapshot:

```
UIImage *snapshotImage = nil;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.tabBarController.view.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
if ([self.tabBarController.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.tabBarController.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES]) {
                snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            }
```

You can capture transitionContext.containerView for this. Pass this image to your new VC and set it as the background to that VC's view as:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:self.bgImage];
```

P.S. I am not fluent in Swift so you will have to convert the code to swift yourself but hopefully this gives you a decent starting point

Comment: No problem with the objective-c version, one question: there is no way to keep the presentation of the previous controller in the stack ? If you are sure that this is impossible, please, update your question. So i can mark it as the correct answer

Comment: I just did a little test where I set the alpha to 0 for a pushed VC's view and it does not show the VC behind it in the navigation stack. I am using custom transition to animate the push so I am pretty confident that it is not possible. In case of modal presentation, I am sure that the view behind is taken out of the view stack hence you see a black background if you change modal view controller's alpha.